# Ruby hash from range

Tags: ruby

How may I do like that:

```
hash = {}
(140..200).each {|n| h[n] = "#{n} cm"}
```

but in one line which returns whole hash?
I'm sure it's possible, but I dunno how ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very close:

```
hash = (140..200).inject({}) {|h, n| h[n] = "#{n} cm"; h}
```

Comment: Anytime, `inject` is one of the best features of Enumberable once I finally wrapped my head around it :)

Comment: This question pops over and over, the real problem is the lack of enumerable -> hash conversion in Ruby. Inject is just a fancy a verbose way of doing it, but there should be a method for this, Hash[...] is ok but not very efficient (a temporal array is needed). http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/666

Comment: @tokland +1 All really great points from an efficiency and speed standpoint.

Comment: @tokland: The real problem is that there is no explicit stand alone "pair" in Ruby so you have to kludge around with temporary arrays (to simulate pairs) or `inject({})`/`each_with_object({})` solutions. You really want to say `h = x.map { |n| n => "#{n} cm" }` but that doesn't work without laying on extra stuff. Similar issues apply when unpacking a Hash with `each`, your block gets handed a temporary Array and that's a bit kludgey.

Comment: @mu: Exactly my point, because vanilla Ruby does not provide an standard way of converting an enumerable into a hash you'll see some people using each, others inject, others each_with_object, others Hash[...], that's a mess. We need an equivalent of Python's dict(). The thing is facets has had it for years: Enumerable#mash. (140..200).mash { |n| [n, "#{nm} cm"] }. It does not matter how it's implemented, having a standard abstraction is what counts. Something similar to mash should be in the core.

Comment: @mu: I think a [key, value] array works just fine to define a pair. Of course a tuple would be conceptually more fitting, but Ruby has no tuples.

Comment: @tokland: The only problem I see with using `[k,v]` as a pair is that it is an *implicit* pair rather than an *explicit* one. That leaves the implementation to guess at our intent. But yeah, the fundamental problem is the lack of a key abstraction in Ruby. I think we're starting to wander a bit OT though.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
hash = (140..200).each_with_object({}) {|n, h| h[n] = "#{n} cm" }
```

I find that I forget the return value from the block when using [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) without, well, injecting.

You could also use the `Hash[]` constructor:

```
hash = Hash[(140..200).map {|n| [n, "#{n} cm"] }]
```

All the extra intermediate Array instances are a bit wasteful but it probably won't matter.

Comment: +1 for Hash[...]. I always felt that building a hash with inject is just too verbose.

Comment: @tokland: You could do `next n, "#{n} cm"` instead. While the Ruby Language Specification says that this must behave *as if* an intermediary array was constructed, I think that at least the next-generation JRuby compiler is able to optimize them away completely, and I wouldn't be too surprised if Rubinius and possibly IronRuby, MacRuby and MagLev did that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[(140..200).map {|n| next n, "#{n} cm" }]
```

Comment: Assuming the `next` was deliberate, why does it behave differently with or without the `next`?

Comment: Because `n, "#{n} cm"` is simply not syntactically valid.

Comment: but why is one specified as valid while the other isn't? Shouldn't it be consistent?